# state params not getting in other state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where when I click on a link i need to change the route and also add send some params to the other state.

The issue here is the params are empty when I console it in other state

```
<div ng-repeat="items in vm.Items">
    <a ng-click="vm.goToDetails(items.id)">{{items.title}}</a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 vm.goToDetails = function(Id) {
     $state.go('Details', {
          'fid': Id
     });
 }
```

route:

```
  $stateProvider.state('Details', {
    url: '/details/:fid',
    resolve: {
        selectedProduct: ['$state', '$stateParams',
            function($state, $stateParams) {
                console.log($stateParams.fid) //getting empty string here
                console.log($state.params.fid)//getting undefined here
            }
        ]
    }
 });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a console in vm.goToDetails console.log(Id) are you getting proper data there?

Comment: Can you see the result of `{{item.title}}`?

Comment: are params visible in URL?

Comment: No the code is correct second line ($state.params.fid) is wrong,add a return $stateParams.fid

Comment: @ParshuramKalvikatte Yes, but before going to other state i just need to check the params and call a service using that param id if that id is present then move further to the state other wise $state.go('some other state')

Comment: `ng-click="vm.goToDetails(items.id)"` in this line `items.id`may be empty, paste the `vm.Items` or `console.log(Id)` in your funciton.

Comment: @Sravan item.id is not empty infact when i console in controller function goToDetails i am getting the id

Comment: until and unless you have any issue in the remaining code of yours which is not mentioned here, it should work fine. any errors in console?

Comment: Yes the code is correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the parameters name in the route url:
/some-route/:fid

Comment: In route above u can see i have mentioned it in the url

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any issue with the code, may be the issue is with the injection of `resolved parameter`.

**I created a DEMO with your code**. This may be helpful to you.

Here is config,

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){


  $stateProvider.state('Details', {
    url: '/details/:fid',
    templateUrl: 'detail.html',
    controller: 'DetailController',
    resolve: {
        selectedProduct: ['$state', '$stateParams',
            function($state, $stateParams) {
                console.log($stateParams.fid) //getting empty string here
                alert($stateParams.fid) //getting empty string here
                return $stateParams.fid

            }
        ]
    }
  });



  $stateProvider.state('login',{
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});
```

Controller that contains repeated object,

```
app.controller('LoginController',function($scope,$state){

  $scope.Items = [{id: 1,title: "Title1"},{id: 2,title: "Title2"},{id: 3,title: "Title3"}] 

   $scope.goToDetails = function(Id) {
     console.log(Id)
     $state.go('Details', {
          'fid': Id
     });
  }

})
```

This is the controller where you can inject **`selectedProduct`**

```
app.controller('DetailController',function($scope,$state,selectedProduct){
  $scope.selectedProduct = selectedProduct;
})
```

[**PLEASE CHECK THIS DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/bzSbBPqLroJP6o1IUV78?p=preview)

Comment: @tania saxena, please check my answer.